# Wait the user for 2 secs before submitting the form

Tags: jquery

I have the following code for submitting forms:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    ...
}
```

I would like to wait the user for about 2 seconds before entering this submit event. **Possible?** Maybe a beforesubmit event?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "wait the user"? You want to delay form submission  for two seconds and then submit?

Comment: Yes I want to delay for two seconds before submitting.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but I'm curious **why** you'd want to do it. Seems totally unnecessary - and potentially confusing for the user - to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $(this).submit();
  }, 2000);
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

With e.preventDefault() you cancel the default behavior of the form (submit, for instance). Then you create a timeout that will execute the real submit.

Maybe you should set a flag, because using .submit() may trigger "submit" event that you are listening to. If so, try with:

```
var attach_timeout = true;

$('form').submit(function (e) {
  if (attach_timeout) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).submit();
    }, 2000);
    attach_timeout = false;
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: Call `.submit()` on the actual form, not a jQuery object containing it, and you won't trigger any submit event handlers attached using jQuery.